# What orchestral compositions have parts for Trumpet in H?

Tags: classical-music, history, orchestra, trumpet, transposition

I know I've played parts written in `H`, but I can't find any from Google search. `H` is the German equivalent of `B`. Source: http://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/names-keys-french-german-italian-and-spanish

Comment: This looks more appropriate to https://musicfans.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if B trumpets are (or were ever) a thing. They don't seem to be commonplace nowadays, and early (pre-romantic) composers are not likely to call for them because B is a pretty remote key area. However, some books (e.g. Piston's *Orchestration*, as well as Adler's book by the same name) do mention the B crook for natural trumpets, so it might have been in use somewhere. Neither of them give examples, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German music, Trumpet in B actually means Bb and H means B (natural). It's quite uncommon, but I have also seen Trumpet in B (not Bb) in some French classical music as well, in one case I think it was a flute concerto, but it's been years since I played it and I do not recall the composer.

Brahms 1st Symphony is one, calls for C, E and B.
Brahms 2nd as well.  D and B

It's fairly rare, but you either play it on a C trumpet (down a half step on everything) or a Bb (up a half-step on everything).  You get used to it after a while.

Most classical rep that's public domain now (almost all from the period where B was being used) is available on IMSLP (internet repository).  If you dig around, especially under German composers, you should be able to find more examples.

Comment: Thanks! Brahms 1st symphony is the one I was thinking of.